# Get textbox value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

No matter what I've tried, I cannot get the value of a textbox in my jQuery function. I know there is a value there, I can see it. However my code below comes back at "undefined" for the value. I cannot figure out why.

I have a js file that is referenced on my asp.net page. On my asp.net page, I have a button that triggers a function on click.

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnNext" runat="server" OnClientClick="TransactionType(); return false;" ImageUrl="~/next.png" />
```

My jQuery code:

```
function TransactionType() {
    var PType = $("#TxtPTypeValue").val;

    alert(PType);

    if (PType == "CC") {
        SubmitCCTransaction();
    } else if (PType == "EC") {
        SubmitECheckTransaction();
    };

};
```

The part that isn't working is this: `var PType = $("#TxtPTypeValue").val;` which comes back as "undefined".

Comment: When you accept an answer, please leave the question as it is - by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59832896/revisions) it to just say "solved" the answers no longer make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix in this way

```
$("#TxtPTypeValue").val();
```

```js
$("#BtnNext").on("click", function(){
   console.log($("#TxtPTypeValue").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type = "text" id = "TxtPTypeValue" /> 
<button id="BtnNext">BtnNext</button>
```

**Updated**

According to @sh1rts's comment, you should also make sure that

> Add a ClientIdMode="Static" to that  definition, without
>   this it won't have that ID on the actual page

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, but I still get undefined. Any other ideas?

Comment: Make sure that you have a `textbox` with id `TxtPTypeValue`. So you should give us your HTML content accordingly.

Comment: I am using  <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPTypeValue" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Add a ClientIdMode="Static" to that <asp:TextBox> definition, without this it won't have that ID on the actual page (which you can confirm by doing a View Source)

Answer (score 1):

**Correct Syntax**

```
$('#TxtPTypeValue').val()
```

**When used to return value:**

This method returns the value of the value attribute of the FIRST matched element.

**When used to set value:**

This method sets the value of the value attribute for ALL matched elements.

[Source of information here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp)

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, but I still get undefined. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Val` is a function, so you have to call it like this `val()`.

Try the below code.

```js
function TransactionType() {
    var PType = $("#TxtPTypeValue").val();
    alert(PType);
    if (PType == "CC") {
       // SubmitCCTransaction();
    } else if (PType == "EC") {
       // SubmitECheckTransaction();
    };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <textarea id="TxtPTypeValue"></textarea>
 <button onclick="TransactionType()">Print Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:text').val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtvalue" value="425656">
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass client id of you control, if you are going to use the value of a server-side control,
for example :

```
$("#<%=TxtPTypeValue.ClientId%>").val();
```